# How to use printui.exe with a value containing the printer name

Tags: for-loop, batch-file, newline, printers

Im trying to make a small script that will automatically remove all printers except the ones that are part of the OS (Microsoft to PDF, OneNote, etc).

I tried to filter them one by one in a *for loop* but for some reasons, it say that it wont recognise the printer name.

I echoed the result instead to see what goes in and the name of the printer seemed to be right.

So im thinking that there could be a newline character at the end of my value and I would like to know how to make sure that the name is correctly outputed in the printui.exe command.

```
REM Loop that will go through all printer name that are installed on the computer
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('wmic printer get name') do (
    REM Verify if the printer name contain "Microsoft", "OneNote" or "Name"
    echo %%a | findstr /i "Microsoft OneNote Name" > nul
    if errorlevel 1 (
        REM Delete the printer that dosent contain any of the word mentionned before
        echo %%a
        printui.exe /dl /n %%a
    ) else (
        REM Delete nothing
    )
)
```

The code above resulted in a error messagebox saying that it don't recognise the printer, that it might be disconnected or the printer name is wrong. (which is not right to me)

I expected the command to work without error and say that the process was completed.

Comment: Try `printui.exe /dl /n "%%a"`

Comment: `printui.exe /dl /n "%%a"` gives me the same result

Comment: Im not sure I understand what you mean... With `""` or without `""`, I get the same errorbox message.
I also want to mention that if I manually type de command in cmd with the correct printer name, the command work correctly and proceed to delete the printer without error.

Comment: The reason that make me think that there might be a newline character in the value is because the last result say `ECHO is disabled` which mean that the value must be empty if im not wrong. The command that return the printer name shouldn't return an empty line anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION 
for /f "delims=" %%b in ('wmic printer get name') do for /f "delims=" %%B in ("%%b") do (

 REM Verify if the printer name contain "Microsoft", "OneNote" or "Name"
 echo %%B | findstr /i "Microsoft OneNote Name" > nul
 if errorlevel 1 (
 REM Delete the printer that dosent contain any of the word mentionned before
 SET "myprinter=%%B"
 CALL :mangle
 echo %%B --- !myprinter! ---
 printui.exe /p /n !myprinter!
 ) else (
  REM Delete nothing
 )
)
GOTO :EOF

:: IF the printername myprinter contains spaces, replace with `" "`
:mangle
IF "%myprinter:~-1%"==" " SET "myprinter=%myprinter:~0,-1%"&GOTO mangle
SET "myprinter=!myprinter: =" "!"
GOTO :eof
```

**Always verify against a test directory before applying to real data.**

This is a strange one. If the printer name eg `HP LaserJet CP 1025` contains spaces, then it must be entered as `HP" "LaserJet" "CP" "1025` - and yes, I've double-checked that. Reference to off-site URL: [Spiceworks - set up printer](https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/2211881-windows-10-how-to-set-the-default-printer-for-all-users)

I've used the `/p` option as I don't want to delete printers.

Comment: This work arround did the trick, thank you so much for your help !

Comment: IMPORTANT MENTION ! the `GOTO :EOF` in line 17 is making the program crashing at the end of the loop. If you remove it, it still work. You should edit it as I want you to keep credits for finding the solution

Comment: What do you mean by "crashing"? Once the `for` loop has ended, there is nothing more to do. In this instance, removing that `goto` will cause the `:mangle` to be excuted one more time which merely changes the value of `myprinter` and then terminates the batch, so it should make no actual difference - the batch should terminate in the same way. What difference have you observed?

Comment: @KJ That might explain why sometimes my value ended up empty instead.. I am still learning batch coding at the moment so I might be wrong too.

Comment: @Magoo When I included your code in a part of a batch as a test, the program would abruptly close without continuing the rest of the code. The batch file would close up no matter what comes after when it reach `GOTO :EOF` at line 17